# i try to get website speed of some website, but i can read only ''domain.com'' i can't read website files like css , js why?

Tags: php, proxy, httpwebrequest, http-get

i try to get website speed of some website, but i can read only ''domain.com'' i can't read website files like css , js ... why ? i use proxies for this job.

here is the php code:

```
$options = array(
                    'useragent'      => "Firefox (+http://www.firefox.org)", // who am i
                    'connecttimeout' => 120, // timeout on connect
                    'timeout'          => 120, // timeout on response
                    'redirect'          => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
                    'referer'           => "http://www.google.com",
                    'proxyhost'        =>'85.25.8.14:80'
            );
$response = http_get("http://solve-ict.com/wp-content/themes/ict%20theme/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", $options , $info);
```

but it works fine with http://solve-ict.com/

but with files css or js it gives 404

using some free proxy servers available

Comment: Could be a number of reasons. Are you going to post the site you're having problems with?

Comment: sometimes it works sometimes not..
it can be http/https problem may be